# mule4 date format parsing issue, when parsing 2019-02-27T15:43:38.38 in dataweave 2.0 Unable to parse 'T'

Tags: java, mule, dataweave, mule-esb, mule4

I am trying to format current time to yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:59:59 
but in dataweave 2.0 getting below exception for 'T'.

Below is my dataweave code:

`StopDate: now() as String{format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:59:59'}`

## Exception

`Message               : "org.mule.weave.v2.parser.exception.ParseException: Unable to resolve variable T
{StopDate: (currentTimeStamp) as String{format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:59:59'}}),                                                                   ^" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0`

I am new to Mule4, please guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using single quotes ' ' within single quotes.

You can either change it so they are single quotes within double quotes:

```
{StopDate: (currentTimeStamp) as String{format: "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:59:59"}}
```

Or escape the quotes:

```
{StopDate: (currentTimeStamp) as String{format: 'yyyy-mm-dd\'T\'HH:59:59'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response it didn't worked for double quotes but it is working after escape the quotes.